# How can we call one route from another route with parameters in Flask?

Tags: python, flask

I am sending a POST request from one form with two inputs to a Flask route.

```
  <form action = "http://localhost:5000/xyz" method = "POST">
     <p>x <input type = "text" name = "x" /></p>
     <p>y <input type = "text" name = "y" /></p>
     <p><input type = "submit" value = "submit" /></p>
  </form>
```

The Flask code is like this.

```
@app.route('/xyz', methods = ['POST', 'GET'])
def xyz():
    if request.method == 'POST':
       x = request.form["x"]
       y = request.form["y"]
       callonemethod(x,y)
    return render_template('index.html', var1=var1, var2=var2)
       #abc(x,y) #can i call abc() like this .i want to call abc() immediately, as it is streaming log of callonemethod(x,y) in console.

@app.route('/abc', methods = ['POST', 'GET'])       
def abc():
    callanothermethod(x,y)
    return render_template('index.html', var1=var3, var2=var4)
    #I want to use that x, y here. also want to call abc() whenever i call xyz()
```

How can I call one route from another route with parameters in Flask?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You have two options.

**Option 1**:
Make a redirect with the parameters that you got from the route that was called.

If you have this route:

```
import os
from flask import Flask, redirect, url_for

@app.route('/abc/<x>/<y>')
def abc(x, y):
  callanothermethod(x,y)
```

You can redirect to the route above like this:

```
@app.route('/xyz', methods = ['POST', 'GET'])
def xyz():
    if request.method == 'POST':
       x = request.form["x"]
       y = request.form["y"]
       callonemethod(x,y)
       return redirect(url_for('abc', x=x, y=y))
```

See also the [documentation](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/quickstart/#redirects-and-errors) about redirects in Flask

**Option 2:**
It seems like the method `abc` is called from multiple different locations. This could mean that it could be a good idea to refactor it out of the view:

In utils.py

```
from other_module import callanothermethod
def abc(x, y):
  callanothermethod(x,y)
```

In app/view code:

```
import os
from flask import Flask, redirect, url_for
from utils import abc

@app.route('/abc/<x>/<y>')
def abc_route(x, y):
  callanothermethod(x,y)
  abc(x, y)

@app.route('/xyz', methods = ['POST', 'GET'])
def xyz():
    if request.method == 'POST':
       x = request.form["x"]
       y = request.form["y"]
       callonemethod(x,y)
       abc(x, y)
```

Comment: good to see your answer but i am returning and rendering in both method. so i can't redirect

Comment: can you please check my updated question ? . try to update answer if possible. it will be great help

Comment: what about option 2 then? You could decouple the abc() method and call from within both routes.