# How to trigger a button by flask?

Tags: javascript, python, html, button, flask

I am running a web server by Flask. I need python flask code to trigger submit button to be clicked on the HTML page. Then the page can "POST" data to the server. In the entire process, I should not click any buttons on the HTML page. Only thing I can do is to start the server at the very beginning. Does anyone know how to do that?
Thanks.

I know how to "POST" data from client-side. I only need to allow the server-side to trigger button at the beginning. I looked up the "RESPONSE" but can not figure out.

HTML:

```
<form action="" method="POST">
<label> Username </label>
    <input type="text" id="trans" name="username" value={{request.form.username}}>

    <button type=”submit”> Submit </button>
</form>
```

I currently have a web contain a recorder. I will play sound on my server and use iPhone and android phone to access the web to test the difference voice quality between devices. I need the server to trigger the button at the very beginning on multiple clients so they can start to record at the same time.

Comment: It's not very clear what you're asking

Comment: "In the entire process, I should not click any buttons on the HTML page." I think what @Jennifer is asking is to be able to programatically trigger an endpoint that is normally triggered by submitting a form.

Comment: [Here's a potentially useful resource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48148131/how-can-we-call-one-route-from-another-route-with-parameters-using-python-flask) if I'm right.

Comment: You question is not clear. The point of having a button is to let users click them and post data to the flask server. If you want to "post" data from flask to flask, you don't need html at all. Just call a function. So, what exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: The question has been updated.

Answer (score 0):

On the Flask server you need to have a function that receives the form once the submit button is clicked.

```
from flask import Flask
from flask import request

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/handle_form>', methods = ['GET', 'POST', 'DELETE'])
def handle_form:
```

In the html you need to make sure the action of the form points to the url of `/handle_form` of the website :

```
<form action="{{ url_for('handle_form') }}" method="POST">
<label> Username </label>
    <input type="text" id="trans" name="username">

    <button type=”submit”> Submit </button>
</form>
```

The value of the input `username` cannot be obtained from the server before this form is submitted. I do not understand why you are trying to access the value of this form from server before submitting it.

Comment: I know how to send data from client to server. What I need is to have action on client button by the server.