# flask request from own site

Tags: python, flask, python-requests

```
@app.route('/bInfo', methods = ['POST', 'GET'])
def create():
    result = []
    ....
    return jsonify(result)
```

I would like to make a request from '/bInfo'

```
@app.route('/')
def index():
    js = request.json('/bInfo') #this is not working
    print(js)
    return render_template('index.html')
```

How could I do that?

Comment: Don't. Don't go through the entire network stack with external requests, when you can get the same information internally by calling the same code `create` does. If your server is single-threaded, you'll even get into a deadlock situation where it'll be stuck trying to make the request to itself which can't be handled because it's already in the middle of handling a request.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can we call one route from another route with parameters in Flask?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48148131/how-can-we-call-one-route-from-another-route-with-parameters-in-flask)

Answer (score 0):

Anyways, you can do one of the following:

**1. Refactor getting the contents of `/bInfo` outside of the route itself.**
This is mostly self-explanatory. You're just moving the code that makes the contents outside, and calling it in both routes.

**2. Request the page you need using `requests.get()` from [requests](https://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/) and use that.**
You'd need to request from localhost, and this will make one route rely on the other. Option 1 is *much* safer.