# Should a Flask Web App use its own API? if yes, then how does a Web App use its own API?

Tags: python, flask

I am building a web app using python flask and intend to build mobile applications later on.
Currently, I am using SQL alchemy and SQLite DB. So in my routes I am able to get the user details and display them.
For example, on the route of displaying the user's profile page, I can query the DB and access the particular user and display it's values using Jinja2 and render template.

Since, later on I intend to move to multi platform (ie. Mobile Applications), I thought it would be best to create APIs.

So, I have made a few APIs such as getting the user details (first name, last name etc).
These APIs require token authentications.

Now, my question is, should my Web App also use these APIs? Eg- to display user's details on their profile page?

If yes, then how can a route/view function in the flask App access these APIs?
by making a GET request? is that the correct approach?

OR, should the APIs be only for mobile applications??

Please if anyone could help.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whether should you use Flask API for the web application is up to you , but you can if you want to.

You have multiple options for using the API in your frontend:

- Use JS/HTML for the frontend and call the API using Ajax
- Frontend frameworks such as Vue.js, React, Angular

If you decided not to use the API for the web, you will have duplicate code all over and you will need to repeat the same functionalities for both the Web app and the mobile app.

Also you can you use a hybrid framework for both web/mobile applications so you have a single code for the frontend. There are multiple frameworks to choose from such as:

- Ionic - easy to learn and is similar to web development. You write Ionic apps in Vue.js, React, Angular.
- React Native. Uses React as the frontend framework.
- Flutter uses Dart programming language

Comment: Thank you for the insights. A couple of follow up questions: 
1. To access the APIs from web app (Flask) I would need to use requests.get(),  and that would create an extra get request? These extra requests are the tradeoff (downside) for a systematic approach in order to NOT duplicate the code all over? 

2. Is this the standard and correct approach to follow? (ie. using APIs for web as well. so that code duplication does not happen)?

Comment: 1. Why would you use requests.get()? If I understood your intention correctly, you are thinking of having the controllers for the web app call the APIs for mobile application?

2- I'm sure if I can say that is the standard, but it is the easier approach to use in the long run. Using a single endpoint for all requests reduces code duplication and increases consistency.

Comment: Thank you for the response. I am using python (flask) for web-app. Wouldnt I need to do requests.get() in the flask routes/view functions to get the data from the api?? is there any other way?

Comment: Instead of using requests.get() in order to get data from the API, you can make a move the logic in the route to a function that would be called by multiple endpoints.

Check the first answer to see an example of what I mean: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48148131/how-can-we-call-one-route-from-another-route-with-parameters-in-flask)

Comment: Thank you, I had thought and tried the same. I tried to import the function (the API function) and call it from the route. However, since the API function is protected by token authorisation (which is sent in the Header of the request), simple importing and calling the function gives the error of "Unauthorised". So, how can I call or use the API within the same app? (the API is protected by token - which is sent in the Header of a GET request). Any approach if you could suggest? thanks

Comment: please let me know your thoughts on the above comment. thanks.

Comment: You shouldn't import the API function which is protected, you need to create a separate function (regular python function, not a route) that you will use any where in your application.

`def sum(num1, num2): # This route can be called by multiple API endpoints without the need of authorization or making a GET request
    return num1 + num2

@authorized_route
def api_route():
    sum(10, 20)`

Comment: No no, the reverse is what is required, but not happening.  I need to use the data returned by the API. So, I need to call the API in some function or route. That is not being allowed. How can I access the data returned by the API?? The access is required in another python function or route? please let me know your view, it is killing my mind. thanks.

Comment: I understand what you want to achieve, but what I'm suggesting is to move the logic to a function that does not need any authentication, and this function can be used in any route.

If you are insisting in making an API call to the authorized route then you can pass the authorization key to the request headers as follows: 
`requests.get(url, headers={"access-key":"SECRET"})`

Comment: I am not insisting on making an API call. On the contrary, I wanted to avoid it - but it appears not to be possible. As per your suggestion, I can move the logic to a function that does not need authentication, but that Logic requires data from the Database. How do I get that data from the DB? thanks.

Comment: You can put the function right next to your routes and make DB calls, it should work fine.